# VueJS props are not passing to component via router-link

Tags: vue.js

I have the following link in a VueJS component:

```
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'time', props: { tax: 123, site: site_key }}">Add New Request</router-link>
```

The Time component has the following code, its always showing the default, instead of the value:

```
<template>
  <div>t {{ tax }} {{site}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Time",
        props: {
            tax: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Vue!'
            },
            site: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Vue!'
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

EDITED

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name:'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/time',
      name:'time',
      component: Time,
      props: { tax: null, site: null }
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Can you please include your routes.js file?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in Vue Router :

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Props are passed by the params field, so like this :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'time', params: { tax: 123, site: site_key }}">Add New Request</router-link>
```

for a much more insight on your problem, please include your `router.js` file.